# Bootstrap full width design

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to style the `div` like the image  below.

[image]

I have designed some but its not full `width` and it also shows side scroll in mobile view.

Please tell me how to do it in full `width`.

My HTML Code

```css
#news_and_cv {
  background: #e6e6e6;
}
#send_cv {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  padding: 25px 0px 20px 0px;
}
#news {
  background: #02bed4;
  padding: 25px 0px 20px 0px;
}
.submit {
  padding: 13px 20%;
  background: #02bed4;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.submit:hover {
  background: #02bed4;
}
.form-style {
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  height: 37px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.attach {
  margin-left: 10%;
  float: left;
}
#send_cv form,
input {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.news_detail {
  padding: 0px 15px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 13px;
  margin-top: 13px;
}
.news_detail p {
  text-align: justify;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.news_detail a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.head_title_main {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Marcellus';
  font-size: 35px;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: #505050;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="news_and_cv">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-7" id="send_cv">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="head_title_main">Send Your CV</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <form style="text-align:center;">
              <input class="form-style" type="text" placeholder="First Name" />
              <br/>
              <input class="form-style" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" />
              <br/>
              <input class="form-style" type="email" placeholder="Email" />
              <br/>
              <input class="form-style" type="tel" placeholder="Phone" />
              <br/>
              <input class="attach" type="file" /> <span>Attach CV (pdf, doc, docx)</span>
              <br/>
              <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--end of col-md-7-->

      <div class="col-md-5" id="news">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="head_title_main">News</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="news_detail">
              <h4>Urgent opening for Electrical Engineering</h4>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor amet, consectetur adipite scinelit vestibulum vel quam sitare amet odio ultricies dapbus acer vitae.</p>
              <span>06/06/2016</span>  <span class="pull-right"><a href="#">Read more</a></span>
              <hr>
            </div>

            <div class="news_detail">
              <h4>Urgent opening for Electrical Engineering</h4>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor amet, consectetur adipite scinelit vestibulum vel quam sitare amet odio ultricies dapbus acer vitae.</p>
              <span>06/06/2016</span>  <span class="pull-right"><a href="#">Read more</a></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--End of col-md-5-->
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: use `container-fluid` class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), for full-width, you have to use `.container-fluid` instead of `.container` which is restrain to `width:1170px` in desktop view.

and remove nested `.rows` inside `.col-md-*` otherwise it will cause h-scrollbar

to remove the h-scrollbar in extra-small devices you have to use `xs` class, by using `.col-xs-12`

```css
#news_and_cv {
  background: #e6e6e6;
}
#send_cv {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  padding: 25px 0px 20px 0px;
}
#news {
  background: #02bed4;
  padding: 25px 0px 20px 0px;
}
.submit {
  padding: 13px 20%;
  background: #02bed4;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.submit:hover {
  background: #02bed4;
}
.form-style {
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  height: 37px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.attach {
  margin-left: 10%;
  float: left;
}
#send_cv form,
input {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.news_detail {
  padding: 0px 15px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 13px;
  margin-top: 13px;
}
.news_detail p {
  text-align: justify;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.news_detail a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.head_title_main {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Marcellus';
  font-size: 35px;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: #505050;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section id="news_and_cv">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-7" id="send_cv">

            <div class="head_title_main">Send Your CV</div>

            <form style="text-align:center;">
              <input class="form-style" type="text" placeholder="First Name" />
              <br/>
              <input class="form-style" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" />
              <br/>
              <input class="form-style" type="email" placeholder="Email" />
              <br/>
              <input class="form-style" type="tel" placeholder="Phone" />
              <br/>
              <input class="attach" type="file" /> <span>Attach CV (pdf, doc, docx)</span>
              <br/>
              <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
          </div>
      <!--end of col-md-7-->

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5" id="news">

        <div class="head_title_main">News</div>
        <div class="news_detail">
          <h4>Urgent opening for Electrical Engineering</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor amet, consectetur adipite scinelit vestibulum vel quam sitare amet odio ultricies dapbus acer vitae.</p>
          <span>06/06/2016</span>  <span class="pull-right"><a href="#">Read more</a></span>
          <hr />
        </div>

        <div class="news_detail">
          <h4>Urgent opening for Electrical Engineering</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor amet, consectetur adipite scinelit vestibulum vel quam sitare amet odio ultricies dapbus acer vitae.</p>
          <span>06/06/2016</span>  <span class="pull-right"><a href="#">Read more</a></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--End of col-md-5-->
```

Comment: There is side scroll in extra small device. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle of you're initial problem: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/ for ref...

By turning off the max-width on the .container using .container-fluid and using the display-table display you can achieve full width, full height columns.

I've also used a @media query to turn these on for devices above mobile and not interfere with the stacked layout.

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/22102/

```
 <section id="news_and_cv">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-7 " id="send_cv">
        <h2>Send Your CV</h2>
        <form class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" type="text">
          <br>
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" type="text">
          <br>
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="Email" type="email">
          <br>
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" type="tel">
          <br>
          <input class="attach" type="file"> <span>Attach CV
                        (pdf, doc, docx)</span>
          <br>
          <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
      </div>
      <!--end of col-md-7-->
      <div class="col-md-5 " id="news">
        <h2>News</h2>
        <div class="news_detail">
          <h4>Urgent opening for Electrical Engineering</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor amet, consectetur adipite scinelit vestibulum vel quam sitare amet odio ultricies dapbus acer vitae.</p><span>06/06/2016</span> <span class="pull-right"><a href="#">Read more</a></span>
          <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="news_detail">
          <h4>Urgent opening for Electrical Engineering</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor amet, consectetur adipite scinelit vestibulum vel quam sitare amet odio ultricies dapbus acer vitae.</p><span>06/06/2016</span> <span class="pull-right"><a href="#">Read more</a></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--End of col-md-5-->
    </div>
  </div>
</section>



.row {
  display: table;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #news,
  #send_cv {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
        width: 50%;
  }
}

#news_and_cv {
  background: #e6e6e6;
}

#news_and_cv .container-fluid{
  padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

#news_and_cv h2 {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  h2text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Marcellus';
  font-size: 35px;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: #505050;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#send_cv {
  background: #e6e6e6;
}

#news {
  background: #02bed4;
}

.btn.btn-default {
  padding: 13px 20%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #02bed4;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: block;
}

.news_detail {
  padding: 0 15px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 13px;
  margin-top: 13px;
}

.news_detail p {
  text-align: justify;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.news_detail a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```